# Calling functions with axios requests in it in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

When I try to call functions containing axios requests from jest or simulate a click event, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError
      at XMLHttpRequest.open (/home/pravesh/senvion/v1.1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:486:15)
      at xhrAdapter (/home/pravesh/senvion/v1.1/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:41:11)
      at executor (/home/pravesh/senvion/v1.1/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:27:9)
      at dispatchRequest (/home/pravesh/senvion/v1.1/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:11:10)
```

Now my dispatcher is written in promise(*axios.then(*here*)*) of axios request. So I am not able to access the updated state of the component. When I access the states from Store, I only get the initialized state because axios is giving error and I am not able to update the state.

Can I get some help regarding this issue ?

Comment: You should link related code. Hard to judge what's happening. And regarding how you use axios in your description, you surely mean axios(yourRequest).then(*dispatcher here*), right?

Comment: Basically its not possible to hit api request from jest test file. So when an external function is called from jest containing a ajax call, it gives the above error

Comment: Yes @daft300punk u r right. I mean that only

Comment: You can mock all your axios calls. Jest also lets you test for promises, both resolution and failure. Just remember to return your promise. See the 4th snippet here - https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html. The one with - return user.getUserName(4).then

Comment: If I dont want to mock and hit the actual request, what can be the solution ? I know that should not be done but is there a way I can do that ?